# Change the colour of Keyboard in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-softkeyboard

Hi is there any way of changing the colour of keyboard or we have to get some custom keyboard for it , any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [A custom keyboard, the easy way.](http://oneweekapp.com/log/a-custom-keyboard-the-easy-way/)

Basically, use the default keyboard and overlay it with an image.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no way to change keyboard appearance in public api.